# Display multiple square box in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell that contains one textField for name for title.
I have to display 16 small squre box in that cell to allow the user to select a color.? Which iOS Controller I should use?And how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a UIButton (actually 16 of them), set it's backgroundColor to your colors.